# Lucene Query Boosting

Tags: java, lucene

I am reading 2 query from file like,

```
Query q1 = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "id", analyzer).parse(dis.readLine());
Query q2 = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "id", analyzer).parse(dis.readLine());
```

I want these query to be combined as one query and give some boost (say by 5) to query 2 i.e q2.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
q2.setBoost(5);

BooleanQuery q3 = new BooleanQuery();
q3.add(q1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
q3.add(q2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

You searching using the `BooleanQuery` `q3`.

Comment: Thanks. I did it like Query q1 = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Id", analyzer).parse(dis.readLine()); Query q2 = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Id", analyzer).parse(dis.readLine());   
q1.setBoost(5f);Query q = q1.combine(new Query[]{q2, q1});

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can boost a query or not. I know you can boost a field when you create the index e.g.

```
Field field = new Field("id", id, ......);
field.setBoost(0.5);
```

As far as combining those 2 queries:

```
String term = dis.readLine() + " AND " + dis.readLine();
```

Or something to that effect .....

Comment: String term = dis.readLine() + " AND " + dis.readLine() is actually for string and then we can parse this string. But what I need is having 2 query Q1 n Q2 how to combine it. 
I tried q1..setBoost(0.5), no error is coming so Query boosting is possible. I would like to combine boosted queries.