# How to score only one field when using multi-field query?

Tags: lucene

The scenerio is like this: I have to use multi-field query, which indexed several field. When scoring, I want to only consider one field. Say the query is "name='Chris' and age='25'", the final score is calculated according to age only. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some time since I last played with Lucene, but I guess you can:

1. Use `BooleanQuery` consisting of two queries and set individual boosts on them (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549080/lucene-query-boosting)).
2. Use `CustomScoreQuery` (a bit verbose example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924937/lucene-custom-scoring-for-numeric-fields)).